# jQuery add styling to the ID when clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to add styling to the link ID when clicked. I figured how to get the ID of the element but adding the style is not working. Here's my sample code:

```
   <a href="#" id="page_1" class="pagelink" >Page 1</a>
   <a href="#" id="page_2" class="pagelink" >Page 2</a>  

   $('a.pagelink').click(function() { 
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       console.log(id);
       $('#id').css("background","yellow");
   });
```

Comment: use  $('#'+id).css("background","yellow");

Answer (score 8):

You're constructing the query incorrectly.

Last line should be

```
 $('#'+id).css("background","yellow");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're targeting an ID of "id", not the value held in your `id` variable. Use this instead:

```
$('#' + id).css("background","yellow");
```

However fetching the ID here is a bit redundant as you've already got access to the element because of the scope. You could instead use:

```
$('a.pagelink').click(function() {
    $(this).css("background","yellow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  $(this).css("background","yellow");

```js
$('a.pagelink').click(function() { 
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
           console.log(id);
           $(this).css("background","yellow");
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="page_1" class="pagelink" >Page 1</a>
       <a href="#" id="page_2" class="pagelink" >Page 2</a>
```